# intermittent ping failures even though host device has valid IP address

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ping command in my cpp code and my application will use this code to determine whether a particular device in the network is connected or disconnected based on the ping response. We are sending below parameters to ping command
dataBlockSize [56] packetCount [1] timeOut [1] host [IP Address].

For one of the devices intermittently the ping is failing and we are getting packets received as 0. It is intermittent (some times ping is success & some times failure with in span of seconds). I am not sure why ping is failing even though device has valid IP. Can any one please let me know any reasons of ping command failure even though device is connected and has valid IP. If the connection type matters, the device is connected through WiFi.

Comment: Often, it is network congestion. ICMP, which ping uses, is low priority traffic, and it is the first to be dropped in the event there is congestion on the network. Also, the host being pinged could just be too busy to respond. You should check the logs and interfaces of the network devices in the path to see if there is congestion.

Comment: Thanks Ron. Can you please post this as answer. I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, it is network congestion. ICMP, which ping uses, is low priority traffic, and it is the first to be dropped in the event there is congestion on the network. Also, the host being pinged could just be too busy to respond. You should check the logs and interfaces of the network devices in the path to see if there is congestion.

Answer (score 1):

A related question can be found here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211536/network-connection-only-works-for-a-while/211769#211769

and a good answer which helped me. In case you don't want to click the link I've put a bit more information below.

In my case I saw the problem when pinging my network gateway (10.20.0.254) as:

```
$ ping 10.20.0.254
PING 10.20.0.254 (10.20.0.254) 56(64) bytes of data
64 bytes from 10.20.0.254: icmp_seq=4 ttl=255 time=0.815ms
64 bytes from 10.20.0.254: icmp_seq=5 ttl=255 time=0.792ms
64 bytes from 10.20.0.254: icmp_seq=6 ttl=255 time=0.619ms
64 bytes from 10.20.0.254: icmp_seq=7 ttl=255 time=0.781ms
64 bytes from 10.20.0.254: icmp_seq=8 ttl=255 time=0.740ms
64 bytes from 10.20.0.254: icmp_seq=54 ttl=255 time=0.812ms
64 bytes from 10.20.0.254: icmp_seq=55 ttl=255 time=0.757ms
64 bytes from 10.20.0.254: icmp_seq=56 ttl=255 time=0.775ms
64 bytes from 10.20.0.254: icmp_seq=57 ttl=255 time=0.799ms
64 bytes from 10.20.0.254: icmp_seq=58 ttl=255 time=0.748ms
```

Note the gaps in the icmp_seq numbers corresponding to dropped pings.

In the end, my problem was that the DHCP server gave my machine an IP which was already in use (statically allocated I guess). Manually setting an unallocated IP (determined by using a different machine to ping IPs around the IP allocated by the DHCP server) fixed my problem.